# Recognize the Android store with package com.sbinstall

Tags: android

It became in the log that the user's installed my app from the store with package  com.sbinstall

What kind of store is this ?

```
com.vending.android  - Google Play
com.amazon.* - Amazon
com.sbinstall - ?
```

Comment: Have you found the answer to this? I am getting the same log for my app.

Comment: No. That's still unknown.